# Regarding Test Class

Tags: unit-test

```
@isTest
public class test6 {
static testmethod  void test()
{
string check;
system.debug(Test.isRunningTest());   
if(Test.isRunningTest())
check='Test7';
else
check='tyftdytfyudd';
}
    //system.debug(check);
}
```

While Saving the Apex Class:

> Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   Test.isRunningTest()

Comment: Please Anyone Guide Me for the Answer

Answer (score 6):

Most likely you created an Apex Class before with the name `Test`, which will force the compiler to look at your class and try to find the `isRunningTest()` method instead of the standard Apex class.

Answer (score 4):

Test.isRunningTest() is meant to be used in the class that the test is testing not in the test class itself. See the docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_isRunningTest) for more information on that method.

> Returns true if the **currently executing code** was called by code
>   contained in a test method, false otherwise. Use this method if you
>   need to run different code depending on whether it was being called
>   from a test.

Found a helpful article [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000205831&language=en_US) that goes over examples of when to use the method.

> **Other Usage scenarios:**
>
> 1) To ensure the trigger doesn't execute the batch if
>   Test.IsRunningTest() is true, and then test the batch class with it's
>   own test method.
>
> 2) Testing callouts - in your callout code you check to see if you're
>   executing within a unit test context by checking Test.isRunningTest()
>   and instead of getting your callout response from an
>   HttpResponse.send() request, you return a pre-built test string
>   instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a class to your org named Test?

If you add an Apex Class with the same name as a default class in Apex, all calls to that class will look at your class instead of the standard Apex classes.

Comment: please display the code or Answer,i am not able to Understand

Comment: @Elavarasan Your testmethod is called test (line 3 in your question)... try renaming it.

Comment: @Girbot By Renaming the Method also shows same error,please Help

Comment: Others above have already said this but you most likely have another class/method called test - find it and rename it.

Comment: @Elavarasan go to Setup -> Develop -> Apex Classes, do you see a class with the name "Test"?

Comment: @Elavarasan you are welcome, please do mark the best answer in order to help others in the future.